# How to Spy on a Closure or Proxy in spock/groovy?

Tags: groovy, spock

How to Spy on a Closure or Proxy in spock/groovy?

[Spock](http://spockframework.org/) has a limitation that you can't use the following style [interaction testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/interaction_based_testing.html) pattern:

```groovy
setup:
subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"

when:
publisher.send("message1")

then:
1 * subscriber.receive("message1")
```

Because the `1 *` interaction line overrides the stubbed return of the "ok". You have to instead put them both on the same line:

```groovy
1 * subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"
```

Mostly this is ok, but for some cases with the need to stub just a bit more complicated behaviour it'd be really nice to be able to separate stubbed behaviour and interaction like that.

All the things I'm mocking/stubbing can be represented by a `Closure`, but I can't get a `Spy` to a `Closure` to work (or a `Spy` to a `Proxy` to a `Closure`). So I have the following Closure-lite class:

```groovy
#!groovy
import spock.lang.Specification

class C {
    def c
    C (Closure c) { this.c = c }

    def call (Map args = null) { args? c?.call (args) : c?.call() }
    def call (Map args = null, one) { args? c?.call (args, one) : c?.call (one) }
    def call (Map args = null, one, two) { args? c?.call (args, one, two) : c?.call (one, two) }
    // etc.
}
```

That lets the following tests pass despite their separation of stubbed behaviour and interaction:

```groovy
class spyTest extends Specification {

    void "should accept 0 args" () {
        given:
            def foo = Spy (C, constructorArgs:[{return "foo"}])
        when:
            def result = foo ()
        then:
            1 * foo()
            result == "foo"
    }

    void "should accept 1 positional args, 0 named args" () {
        given:
            def foo = Spy (C, constructorArgs:[{ one -> ["foo", one]}])
        when:
            def result = foo (1)
        then:
            1 * foo(1)
            result == ["foo", 1]
    }

    void "should accept 1 args, + 1 named args" () {
        given:
            def foo = Spy (C , constructorArgs:[{ args, one -> return ["foo", args, one]}])
        when:
            def result = foo (1, a:'a')
        then:
            1 * foo(1, a:'a')
            result == ["foo", [a:'a'], 1]
    }

    void "should accept 2 args, + 0 named args" () {
        given:
            def foo = Spy (C , constructorArgs:[{ one, two -> return ["foo", one, two]}])
        when:
            def result = foo (1,2)
        then:
            1 * foo(1,2)
            result == ["foo", 1, 2]
    }

    void "should accept 2 args, + 2 named args" () {
        given:
            def foo = Spy (C , constructorArgs:[{ args, one, two -> return ["foo", args, one, two]}])
        when:
            def result = foo (1,2, a:'a', b:'b')
        then:
            1 * foo(1,2,a:'a', b:'b')
            result == ["foo", [a:'a', b:'b'], 1, 2]
    }

}
```

This is workable, if a little clunky, but obviously it'd be nicer to have a more dynamic "Closure" class than one where I have to add every potential number of parameters.

So is a more dynamic solution possible (how?), or does the fact of using `Spy` or `GroovySpy` prohibit a more dynamic spied-upon class?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate a bit more, everything you have shown can be easily done with mocks no need for a spy.

```
class MockTest extends Specification {

  void "should accept 0 args" () {
    given:
    def foo = Mock (C)
    when:
    def result = foo ()
    then:
    1 * foo() >> 'foo'
    result == "foo"
  }

  void "should accept 1 positional args, 0 named args" () {
    given:
    def foo = Mock (C)
    when:
    def result = foo (1)
    then:
    1 * foo(1) >> { args -> ["foo", args[0]]}
    result == ["foo", 1]
  }

  void "should accept 1 args, + 1 named args" () {
    given:
    def foo = Mock (C)
    when:
    def result = foo (1, a:'a')
    then:
    1 * foo(1, a:'a') >> { args, one -> ["foo", args, one]}
    result == ["foo", [a:'a'], 1]
  }

  void "should accept 2 args, + 0 named args" () {
    given:
    def foo =  Mock (C)
    when:
    def result = foo (1,2)
    then:
    1 * foo(1,2) >> { one, two -> ["foo", one, two]}
    result == ["foo", 1, 2]
  }

  void "should accept 2 args, + 2 named args" () {
    given:
    def foo = Mock (C)
    when:
    def result = foo (1,2, a:'a', b:'b')
    then:
    1 * foo(1,2,a:'a', b:'b') >> { args, one, two -> ["foo", args, one, two]}
    result == ["foo", [a:'a', b:'b'], 1, 2]
  }

}
```

Comment: That combines the interaction and the stubbing. The point is to separate them (because the stub is more complex and clutters the test and / or needs to be reproduced in a few places). The best way I've gotten to achieve that is to spy on a closure, but only with my rather clunky class above, no more generic/dynamic solution.

Comment: I know a mock is able to provide stubbing, but not to separate it from the interaction. The reason I was using a spy is because a spy allows me to have mock interactions, while at the same time having some other functionality separated off somewhere else (which I'm using for the stubbing).

Comment: The problem is that Spy doesn't work for a Closure (or a Proxy to a Closure). So I have this hand made C class, that is not especially dynamic and has to be extended for every signature.

Comment: @idij I still don't quite understand how you want to structure your tests. You seem to want to have the dynamics of stubbing but not inside the spec itself. You could just delegate to other another method that contains the logic `1 * foo() >> {args -> mydelegate(args)}`. In spock 1.1 we added the ability to spy on instances. Or you could look into implementing your own IDefaultResponse https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-core/src/main/java/org/spockframework/mock/EmptyOrDummyResponse.java Maybe you could enhance the example with a more realistic version.

Comment: I want the stub defined outside of the test (e.g in the base fixture). What you wrote with the delegate is pretty much what I have today, but I, and more importantly others, have to know to put in in place and remember to do it. it makes it awkward for me to put in default stubs that others can leverage when they are just interested in the interaction.

Comment: There's a largish set of known in advance functions people might use in their code under test. Mostly it's ok to register a Mock(Closure) as a replacement, but some have complex behaviours that if not stubbed will cause the rest of the code under test to fail while at the same time being sufficiently interesting that people will want to define the interactions (wiping out any default stubs). If people have to stub behaviour themselves, a lot of code will end up as "yeah, I spent a few days but I couldn't test that".